# How can I configure my <li> items with Angular Routing so that it shows the relevant details in a new view?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am building an Angular Movie DB, the two components I am working with are the "search-movie" component and the "single-view" component. The "search-movie" component displays a list of movies, the "single-view" component shows further details of a given movie.

I would like it so that when I click on a movie from the list in the "search-movie" component, the page renders the "single-view" component for that movie.

I have managed to set this up so that navigating to the "single-view" path with a movie id (i.e. /movie/tt4425200) directly from the URL, correctly loads up the info for that movie by it's ID, so that's all correctly set up.

I just can't seem to connect the clicking of a movie in the "search-movie" component, to then successfully navigate to the correct "single-view" path. So using the example above, clicking on the relevant movie loads up the "single-view" component with the URL path /movie/tt4425200.

I'm sure that this is a case of using @Input to communicate between the two components, but I just can't figure it out.

**search-movie.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';

import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-movie',
  templateUrl: './search-movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-movie.component.css']
})
export class SearchMovieComponent implements OnInit {

  searchControl = new FormControl('');
  movieResults: any = [];

  constructor(private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  /* GET request */
  getData(event) {
    const film = event.target.value;
    this.data.searchFilm(film)
    .subscribe( (res) => {
      res = this.movieResults = res;
      console.log(res);
    });
  }
}
```

**search-movie.component.html:**

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="is-size-3">Find your favorite movies...</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <input 
            type="text" 
            (keyup)="getData($event)" 
            placeholder="Start typing..." 
            [formControl]="searchControl" />
    </form>
    {{searchControl.value}}
</div>

<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li id="list-item" *ngFor="let x of movieResults; let i = index;">
            <img [src]="x.Poster" onerror="this.src='../assets/images/default-poster.jpg'">
            <p id="movie-title" class="is-size-5">{{x.Title}} ({{x.Year}}) </p>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**single-view.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-single-view',
  templateUrl: './single-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./single-view.component.css']
})
export class SingleViewComponent implements OnInit {

  singleDetails: any = {};

  constructor(
    private data: DataService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    /** GENERATE FILM DETAILS BY movie/id where id is the imdbID */
    const id = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    this.data.moviebyID(id)
    .subscribe( (res) => {
      res = this.singleDetails = res;
    });
  }

}
```

**single-view.component.html:**

```html
<div class="container singleDisplayContainer">
    <div class="columns is-mobile">
        <div class="column" id="poster-column">
            <img id="poster" [src]="singleDetails.Poster" [alt]="singleDetails.Title" onerror="this.src='../assets/images/default-poster.jpg'">
        </div>
        <div id="info-column" class="column">
            <div class="columns">
                <div class="column is-three-fifths">
                    <h1 class="is-size-3">{{singleDetails.Title}} <span class="is-size-4">({{singleDetails.Year}})</span> </h1>
                    <p style="font-size: 14px"> {{singleDetails.Rated}} | {{singleDetails.Runtime}} | {{singleDetails.Genre}} | {{singleDetails.Released}} </p>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div class="columns">
                        <div class="column is-one-third">
                            <img id="star-rating" width="50px" src="../../assets/images/star-rating.png" alt="{{singleDetails.Title}}">
                        </div>
                        <div class="column">
                            <p style="font-size: 2em"> {{singleDetails.imdbRating}}<span style="font-size: 12px">/10</span></p>
                            <p>{{singleDetails.imdbVotes}}</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <br>
            <p>Plot: {{singleDetails.Plot}} </p>
            <br>
            <p>Directed by: {{singleDetails.Director}} </p>
            <br>
            <p>Writers: {{singleDetails.Writer}} </p>
            <br>
            <p>Actors: {{singleDetails.Actors}} </p>
            <br>
            <p onerror="this.style.display='none'">Box office: {{singleDetails.BoxOffice}} </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your UL -> LI, add routerLink property and pass the movie id as the second param

**[routerLink]="['/movie/,x.movieId]">**

```
<ul>
   <li id="list-item" *ngFor="let x of movieResults; let i = index;" [routerLink]="['/movie/,x.movieId]">
    <img [src]="x.Poster" onerror="this.src='../assets/images/default-poster.jpg'">
    <p 
    id="movie-title" 
    class="is-size-5">{{x.Title}} ({{x.Year}}) </p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yes this is what I wanted not a a child route. I ended up using the following and it works great: [routerLink]="['/movie/' + x.imdbID]">

Comment: this is what i provided right? If it helped. Pl kindly upvote the answer

Comment: Hi @MuruGan, answer has been upvoted but I'm new to Stackoverflow so I'm not sure it will display. Thank you again for the response! :-)

Comment: Accept the answer. if helped

Comment: All done, can you help with another Angular problem I have please? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57006040/in-angular-how-can-i-add-li-items-that-are-in-component-a-to-a-favourite-list

Comment: I have answered it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have everything set up, all you need to do is navigate to `single-view` on click of the movie.

`search-movie.component.ts`

```
showDetails(id : string) {
    this.router.navigate(['movie',{ id }]);
}
```

`search-movie.component.html`

```
<!-- in showDetails you will pass id of the current movie while looping -->
<li id="list-item" *ngFor="let x of movieResults; let i = index;" (click)="showDetails(x.id)">
    <img 
    [src]="x.Poster" 
    onerror="this.src='../assets/images/default-poster.jpg'"
    >
    <p 
    id="movie-title" 
    class="is-size-5">{{x.Title}} ({{x.Year}}) </p>
 </li>
```

This will navigate to `single-view` page. is this what you want right?
or you need to load `single-view` in the same page as the list?