# In Angular how can I add <li> items that are in component A to a favourite list in component B?

Tags: angular

I am creating a movie DB, and I would like it so that when the user is on the "search-movie" component (which displays a list of movies), and then clicks on an "add to fav" button for a movie, that movie is then added to another component called "favourites"?

I have tried using an @Output() EventEmitter but I can't seem to get this to work. I think it would also be better if it was handled from the Service.ts file, but again I am having trouble implementing this and would greatly appreciate your help!

Inside the favourites.component.ts file I have added an empty myFavs=[]; array, ready to push fav movies into.

```
/* search-movie.component.ts */

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search-movie',
  templateUrl: './search-movie.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search-movie.component.css']
})
export class SearchMovieComponent implements OnInit {

  searchControl = new FormControl('');
  movieResults: any = [];

  constructor(
    private data: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  /* GET request*/
  getData(event) {
    const film = event.target.value;
    this.data.searchFilm(film)
    .subscribe( (res) => {
      res = this.movieResults = res;
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

}
```

```
/* search-movie.component.html */

<div class="container">
    <h1 class="is-size-1">Find your favorite movies:</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <input 
        type="text" 
        (keyup)="getData($event)" 
        placeholder="Start typing..." 
        [formControl]="searchControl" />
    </form>
</div>


<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li id="list-item" *ngFor="let x of movieResults; let i = index;">
        <img 
        [src]="x.Poster" 
        onerror="this.src='../assets/images/default-poster.jpg'"
        [routerLink]="['/movie/' + x.imdbID]">
        <p 
        id="movie-title" 
        class="is-size-5">{{x.Title}} ({{x.Year}}) </p>
        <button (click)="" >ADD TO FAVS</button>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

```
/* favourites.component.ts */

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from '../data.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-favourites',
  templateUrl: './favourites.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./favourites.component.css']
})
export class FavouritesComponent implements OnInit {

  myFavs = [];

  constructor(
    private data: DataService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

```
/* favourites.component.html */

<h1>FAVS</h1>

<div class="container">
<ul>
    <li id="list-item" *ngFor="let x of myFavs; let i = index;">
        <img 
        [src]="x.Poster" 
        onerror="this.src='../assets/images/default-poster.jpg'"
        [routerLink]="['/movie/' + x.imdbID]">
        <p 
        id="movie-title" 
        class="is-size-5">{{x.Title}} ({{x.Year}}) </p>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

In data service, create a behaviour subject like below

```
// observable
public favouritesList = new BehaviorSubject<any>({});
public favouritesList$ = this.favouritesList.asObservable();
```

and write a method in the service layer

```
tiggerFavouritesList(data) {
  this.favouritesList.next(data);
}
```

In Component One, when you click on

```
<button (click)="addFavourites(x)" >ADD TO FAVS</button> // call a method like

addFavourites(data) {
 this.dataService.tiggerFavouritesList(data);
}
```

In Component Two, subscribe to the subject

```
this.dataService.favouritesList$.pipe().subscribe(
  response =>{
   console.log(response);
  }
);
```

[How to use Behaviour Subject](https://medium.com/@weswhite/angular-behaviorsubject-service-60485ef064fc)

Answer (score 0):

use `Subject` to store the favorite movies. when user clicks `add to fav`, add it in your favorite component's `myFavs` list.

Reference: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/guide/subject

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that both the components do not share the parent child relationship. When you communicate between 2 components that are not related to each other, then you can do that using a service. All you have to do is declare a subject in your service.

To understand how the subject works, you will need proper understanding of rxjs and subscribing. Basically, when you declare a subject, you can subscribe to it from multiple components. Any change in the subject will be by default be communicated to all the subscribers and hence it is better than event emitter. To maintain the performance of the code, you can (and should) unsubscribe it in the destroy method.

Also, while you implement, make sure that the service that you are using is initialized at the parent level of both components and not on the component level. Say, I have a service S, and 2 components A and B. If both have a common parent, P, then it is better to instantiate the service in P. If they do not share the parent child relationship, then you can do so in app.module.

Declaration of a subject:

`private sub = new Subject<any>();`

To make a change in subject:
`this.sub.next({movieName:'Batman'});`

To read this change, you need to subscribe to the subject in the service.
Once subscribed, you can read it in the following way.

`this.subject.subscribe((obj) => {
    console.log(obj.movieName);
})`

Answer (score 0):

You can use new Subject (RxJS) in common service. After any component can subscribe to this subject, and next will use logic.
Emit event using `.next()` method.